# Tooltip is not working in bootstrap+jquery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-4

I am using tooltip in bootstrap+jquery but its not working properly, css doesnt loading, but bootstrap is working properly in entire project but toopltip doesnt, when i hover on tooltip buttons it start adding their names in bottom.

I have also called the tooptip jquery function

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Where is the HTML markup? You need to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates or reproduces the issue **specifically** described in the question.

Comment: Is that TinyMCE or another wysiwyg editor? If so make sure that the iframe they're in (which is usually where they're in) is also loading bootstrap